# How to prevent programme when windows 10 shutdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, shutdown

I have a program running with a while like a server. When i shutdown my pc windows 10 tell me that the program is still running . Is there any method or fonction to shutdown the server automatically when I turn off my pc And so is there any way to order instructions before the shutdown like killing it.

Can someone please give me an example thanks.

Comment: Did you write this program?

Comment: @Anders Mhh, imagine something like while True : requests.get('google.com')